# Can Lightning calendars be created with thunderbird.cfg?

Tags: thunderbird, lightning, thunderbird-lightning

We have set up a calDav server and are planning deployment within our enterprise but are having trouble creating the calDav calendars in Thunderbird with Thunderbird.cfg, default.js, all.js or user.js. Is there a method of automating the creation of these Calendars in thunderbird or do we have to create an add-on to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Lightning calendars can be created using standard preferences and then injected using the mechanisms you described (Thunderbird.cfg, default.js, all.js, user.js, ...). These are the mandatory prefs:

```
calendar.registry.{uuid}.type = "caldav"
calendar.registry.{uuid}.uri = "https://path/to/calendar/"
calendar.registry.{uuid}.name = "My Calendar"
```

And these are optional:

```
calendar.registry.{uuid}.cache.enabled = true
calendar.registry.{uuid}.color = "#330099"
// id1 must be the key as in prefs.js for the email identity.
calendar.registry.{uuid}.imip.identity.key = "id1"
calendar.registry.{uuid}.readOnly = true
calendar.registry.{uuid}.refreshInterval = 30 // minutes
// visible, i.e checked in the calendar list
calendar.registry.{uuid}.calendar-main-in-composite = true
```

Comment: Could you point to a reference for all the preferences that can be set in thunderbird.cfg?

Comment: There isn't a direct reference I can point to. I can tell you about https://enterprise.thunderbird.net/deploy/mcd-thunderbird-autoconfig which has some more high level information about thunderbird.cfg. The prefs can be any Gecko Platform or Thunderbird preference. You can see some in [all-thunderbird.js](https://searchfox.org/comm-central/source/mail/app/profile/all-thunderbird.js), while others are more hidden.

You can also go to Settings > General > Config Editor to see a list.